# SwiftUI NavigationLink Only Works For Text And Images

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have the following code

```
NavigationLink(destination: Destination(), label: {
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("some text")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(width: 15)
                Text("some text")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
            .padding(.top, -10)
        }
        .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            alignment: .topLeading
        )
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "some-link.com")!)
    }
})
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

clicking on the Text and Image will let me navigate to the Destination() but the white space inside the HStack won't let me go to Destination. Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `.contentShape()` modifier at the bottom of the `HStack`, using for example a rectangle shape. In this case, the whole rectangle wrapping the `HStack` will be tappable.

Like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: Destination(), label: {
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("some text")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(width: 15)
                Text("some text")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
            .padding(.top, -10)
        }
        .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            alignment: .topLeading
        )
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "some-link.com")!)
    }
    .contentShape(Rectangle())       // <- Here!
})
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```